# Delete the Repeated lines/Duplicate lines in a file using Regex

Tags: regex

```
messaging-1.8.2.5000.jar
m-common-1.8.2.5000.jar
validation-api-2.0.1.Final.jar
jboss-logging-3.3.2.Final.jar
classmate-1.3.4.jar
tomcat-servlet-api-10.0.6.jar
picketbox-5.1.0.Final.jar
jboss-security-spi-5.1.0.Final.jar
acl-spi-5.1.0.Final.jar
authorization-spi-5.1.0.Final.jar
common-spi-5.1.0.Final.jar
identity-spi-5.1.0.Final.jar
picketbox-spi-bare-5.1.0.Final.jar
jboss-jaspi-api_1.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar
jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar
jbosssx-5.1.0.Final.jar
common-spi-5.1.0.Final.jar
validation-api-2.0.1.Final.jar
jbosssx-bare-5.1.0.Final.jar
jbossxacml-2.0.8.Final.jar
common-spi-5.1.0.Final.jar
jboss-connector-api_1.6_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar
jboss-jacc-api_1.5_spec-1.0.1.Final.jar
picketbox-commons-1.0.0.final.jar
jboss-jacc-api_1.5_spec-1.0.1.Final.jar
picketbox-acl-impl-5.1.0.Final.jar
hibernate-core-5.4.24.Final.jar
javax.persistence-api-2.2.jar
jboss-jacc-api_1.5_spec-1.0.1.Final.jar
common-spi-5.1.0.Final.jar
antlr-2.7.7.jar
validation-api-2.0.1.Final.jar
common-spi-5.1.0.Final.jar
jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec-1.1.1.Final.jar
common-spi-5.1.0.Final.jar
jandex-2.1.3.Final.jar
```

I have a file which contains 2k jar names, most of them are repeated jar names. So i would like to keep the first occurance and delete the duplicate occurances of any jar. There are 2, 3 or 4 occurances of same jar names as well.

Is there a way we can construct Regex to achive the above goal?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You didn't mention tool/lang. If you want to keep the *first* line and remove the duplicate lines in the latter text, you'd probably need to use a regex flavor that supports lookbehind of variable length. Some pattern like [`\n(.+)$(?<=^\1(?:\n.+)+?)`](https://regex101.com/r/zzc1Ft/1)

Comment: Do you intent to check for duplicate names with or without the version? I'd rather use something like a Set<string> if the language you use provides one and only use regex to strip the version of each line, if required. Even if possible, I imagine a regex checking for duplicates would be a huge hideous thing?

Comment: On most linux(like) shells you can just do: `sort garbage.txt | uniq -u`

Comment: @noel Not terribly hideous, see my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A regex solution could be to run this search+replace combo multiple times:

**Search**

```
(^.*$)([\s\S]*)\1[\r\n]*
```

- `(^.*$)` - capture a line, any line, I don't care; into capture group #1
- `([\s\S]*)` - capture **everything** else into capture group #2
- `\1[\r\n]*` - find duplicate data which we captured in capture group #1 and any newlines after it

**Replace**

```
$1$2
```

- `$1` - keep the original data line
- `$2` - keep the data leading up to the duplicated data

The duplicated data is simply not retained.

---

If you're open to a software solution then it's quite trivial with Notepad++.

Edit -> Line Operations -> Remove Duplicate Lines

[image]

[image]

Comment: @RameshThiyagarajan I'm glad it helped! Please consider marking my answer as correct by using the checkmark =)

Comment: am trying to include the regex you mentioned into a sed command and am getting below  erro, can you help me with this?
"sed: -e expression #1, char 33: Invalid back reference"

Comment: @RameshThiyagarajan Sorry, I'm not familiar with sed.